How to correctly test in JUnit @async and @transacional method for rollback
I needed to run tests for async. The test for sending data from a CSV file works, but the rollback test does not, i.e., it functions but I can't catch the exception in the test in such a way that it passes. In the test, I intentionally want to send some files that will cause a rollback-specifically, files that are not in the database and will trigger an exception in the import method. However, it throws an exception at the level of

mvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult)).
"jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception during import,"

which is the exception I expect, but it is not caught in the context needed to pass the test with the expected exception, and instead, the test fails with that message. How should I write this test to make it correct and passing? When I perform another test where I import the correct files, the asyncDispatch method works properly.
Controller:
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<Void>> upload(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "File is empty");
        }
        log.info("importFile: {}", file.getName());
        return service.importFiles(file.getInputStream())
                .thenApply(result -> ResponseEntity.ok().build());
    }

Service:
    @Transactional
    @Async("Import")
    public CompletableFuture<Void> import(InputStream inputStream) {
       
        try {
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                    .lines()
                    .map(row -> row.split(";"))
                    .peek(row -> countTime(counter, start))
                    .forEach(this::save);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("Exception during import", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Exception during import", e);
        }

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    }

  private void save(String[] params) {
        String facadeKey = params[0].toLowerCase() + "Facade";
        QueryFacade facade = mapOfFacades.get(facadeKey);
        if (facade == null) {
            log.error("No facade found for key: {}", facadeKey);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid file type: " + params[0]);
        }
        Object[] dbParameters = Arrays.copyOfRange(params, 1, params.length);
        jdbcTemplate.update(facade.sqlInsert(), dbParameters);
    }

ControllerTest:
   @Test
    public void testRollback() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile(
                "file", "filename.txt", "text/plain", "rightFile;2.2\nrightFile;3\nwrongFileAndExpectException..;4,5".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 

        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(multipart("/api/v1/import/").file(file))
                .andExpect(request().asyncStarted())
                .andReturn();

        mvc.perform(asyncDispatch(mvcResult))
                .andExpect(result -> assertTrue(result.getResolvedException() instanceof IllegalStateException))
                .andReturn();

        Awaitility.await().atMost(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> {
            Integer count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM file", Integer.class);
            assertEquals(0, count.intValue()); 
        });
    }


I tried disabling async to test the rollback functionality alone, but it didn’t really make much sense
